# ScrollView moves content out of the view

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have this hierarchy, when I try to embed in scrollview everything disapears from the view.. what's wrong? Anybody got an idea?

[image]

Comment: Because the `scrollview` is on top of all the other views. Try changing its size or hide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a layering (or Z-order) issue.  If you drag it up so it's the top node under the view, it will be at the very bottom of the stack when it's drawn.

[image]

Comment: I want to embed all textfields and buttons so I can move them up when keyboard appears.. when I embed everything, it's broken.. Should I add some view (which I won't be using?) below the scroll view?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's happening from your original post, but it sounds like a UITableViewController might be what you want.  It essentially does exactly what you're talking about, automatically.  That is, if you have a cell that contains a UITextField, when that text field becomes a first responder (i.e. it has keyboard focus), it scrolls the UITableView (which is a UIScrollView) up so that the target cell with the text field is visible.